# Login for WP-Admin accidentally set to private

Tags: wordpress

While I am manipulating my wordpress site through backend(WP-Admin), I accidentally set to private the login page.Now accessing mysite/wp-admin return 404.How to re enable it?

Comment: If you found solution, please delete this question, it has no meaning of an existence.

Answer (score 0):

Got it,

Just go to database and set your login page to inherit